# How do I make an approval process only be able to run once?

Tags: approval-process

I have several approval processes running on an object.  Depending on the condition, the process may have like 8 steps, OR it may just reach final status after one step (no one actually approves anything).

In the latter case, sometimes someone hits the submit button, and it approves, and then they do it again.

On the back end of this is a trigger/callout with an @Future.  The recipient is receiving a double submission from us.

Is there a declarative way to make it where you can't re-submit even after it has exited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could:

1. Add a custom checkbox field to the object, Already_Approved__c, that defaults to false (unchecked)
2. Set the approval process entry criteria to require Already_Approved__c to be false
3. The approval process runs a field update to set Already_Approved__c to true upon overall approval and/or rejection

Comment: With SF, the answer is almost always, "Make some more fields!"  I was hoping for an option on the process setup somewhere, but that'll do.

Comment: I agree. There may be an idea to vote on (or create!)